# PHP + SQL -- Counting clicks in multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i stuck at the problem that my code wont count total clicks in multiple rows.

This is how the Database looks

```
id         |     jb_clicks   |      created_time
--------------------------------------------------
1          |     14          |       1475420816
2          |     7           |       1475422200
3          |     9           |       1475422217
4          |     3           |       1475422239
```

I want the result to be 33 (14+7+9+3)

How is this possible?

The current code looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS jb_clicks FROM jb_urls
```

my function:

```
function sumdatabase($select, $statement){
    $config = new mysql_config;

    $link = mysqli_connect($config::MYSQL_HOST,$config::MYSQL_USER,$config::MYSQL_PASS);
    mysqli_select_db($link, $config::MYSQL_DATABASE);

    $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT SUM(".$config::MYSQL_PREFIX."$select) AS jb_clicks FROM $statement");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($link,$result);

    return $row[$config::MYSQL_PREFIX.$select];
}
```

Comment: Hint:  `SUM(jb_clicks)`.

Comment: thats what i tried, the result is just 14, which is the row on top

Comment: `SELECT SUM(jb_clicks) FROM jb_urls;`  try this.

Comment: this is sadly not working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
SELECT SUM(jb_clicks) AS jb_clicks FROM jb_urls
```

COUNT() is used to count the row numbers and SUM() is to calculate the total sum of a column in a table. In your case, it would be SUM(jb_clicks).

Comment: To count clicks, this should be handled in PHP and to sum from the table, that's another issue.

Comment: Put it inside the post and update. This looks confusing in the comment.

Comment: done, i might just add another table that increases a total value

Comment: Yes. You can do so. Are you sure the above counts or sums up the clicks. I can't see anything relevant for counting clicks.

Comment: the click counter is for my statistics page, to count total profile views for every profile, such as Robert got 14 clicks and Peter 7, the stats would say now 21. I tried the solutions above, sadly they are not working

Comment: the integers are saved in the Db, the count doesnt work as i want